# Servlet-handling login cookies

Tags: servlets, cookies, authentication, cookiestore

Imagine that a user in a Java Servlet program signs up with his personal information.
Then if he wants to re-use it he can log in with his username and password submitted before.
I want to know how I am going to check the cookies that were stored in the browser in order to see if a specific username was followed by a specific password. I was wondering if cookies are stored in the same row as they were added or they are stored randomly.

I know I can check them by writing like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i< cookies.length; i++) {    
  Cookie thisCookie = cookies[i];    
  if (thisCookie.getName().equals("usn")) 
  //...
```

but there seems to be the problem,as there could be a number of usernames and passwords stored in the browser but the linking between two of them would be specific.

Comment: Use a DB table for that , user credentials should be fetched from some table and matched with the values retrieved from cookies !!!

Comment: Please clarify. Why do you want to use a cookie in the first place?

Comment: I must use cookies in order to log in to the program and i have to use the username and password submited before among other information.